# Error deleting factor column in empty data.table

Tags: r, data.table

If I have an empty data.table with a factor column, the factor column can't be removed with the `:= NULL` operator. Integer and character columns have no problems.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(numbers = integer(0),
                char.letters = character(0),
                factor.letters = factor(character(0)))
DT[, factor.letters := NULL]
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , `:=`(factor.letters, NULL)) : 
Can't assign to column 'factor.letters' (type 'factor') a value of type 'NULL' (not character, factor, integer or numeric)
```

Note that `DT[, char.letters := NULL]` and `DT[, numbers := NULL]` do not produce errors.

Since factor columns behave differently from character and integer columns, I suspect this is a problem with data.table, but am I doing anything incorrectly?

**Edit**: Previous example used join to create the empty data.table (which was then called `join`), but it can be reproduced just as easily by creating it directly.

Comment: looks like a bug - any other strange properties you've noticed?

Comment: `join[, factor.letters := as.character(NULL)]` seems to work...

Comment: This is the only strange property I've come across.

Comment: +1 nice catch. The issue can be reproduced even easier without join: `DT <- data.table(a = integer(0), b=factor(character(0))); DT[, b := NULL]`

Comment: Do you mind filing a bug [**here**](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?group_id=240&atid=975)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. Now fixed in v1.8.9

> Deleting a (0-length) factor column using :=NULL on an empty
>   data.table
>          now works, [#4809](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&group_id=240&aid=4809&atid=975). Thanks to Frank Pinter for reporting. Test added.